# Select (filtrar por nombre columna) from. Eso existe?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy trabajando con *SQL developer*, en una tabla con una gran cantidad de columnas y necesito hacer un filtro para ir trabajando con el sufijo que representa un producto de algunas columnas (ejemplo `04rut`, `04cliente`, `04monto`).

Podría hacer el `select` colocando nombre por nombre de columna, pero me demoraría demasiado ya que son como 100 campos por producto. (yo no cree esta tabla monstruosamente grande, solo me toco revisarla XD) existe algún método mas sencillo como:

```
Select (filtrar por nombres columnas) from myTabla
```

¿Eso existe?

De antemano gracias

Comment: nop, la única forma sería usando SQL dinámico

Comment: Para entender bien, ¿lo que quieres es hacer un select de todas las columnas de una tabla que comiencen con un mismo prefijo, por ejemplo, `'04'`?

Comment: Si es correcto, pero la tabla a pasado por tantas manos que no necesariamente puede estar al principio puede estar así tambien (monto04, precio04rtx). pero se entiende que lo de 04 pertenecen a un producto X

Comment: @Gabriel: Hice una edición a mi respuesta para que pueda tener el valor que buscas en cualquier parte del nombre de la columna y para incluir las comillas, que serían necesarias en caso de columnas que comiencen con números.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes *generar* dinamicamente la consulta, para ejecutarla.

Por ejemplo, este bloque anónimo que dejo a continuación, genera una consulta *select* para una tabla. Debes ajustar el nombre del propietario, el nombre de la tabla y el valor que debe existir en el nombre de las columnas que quieres incluir en el `select` que dará como resultado.

Al final, *imprime* en pantalla la consulta para que puedas copiarla y pegarla donde quieras ejecutarla.

```
declare 
  miSelect varchar2(10000); 
  tOwner varchar2(100); 
  tName varchar2(200); 
  cContenido varchar2(100); 
 
  cursor cols (aOwner varchar2, aTable varchar2, aContenido varchar2) is 
    select column_name 
      from all_tab_cols tc 
     where tc.owner = aOwner 
       and tc.table_name = aTable 
       and column_name like '%' || aContenido || '%'; 
      
begin 
  tOwner := 'CO'; 
  tName := 'PRODUCTS'; 
  cContenido := 'P'; 
  for rCol in cols(tOwner, tName, cContenido) loop 
    if (miSelect is null) then 
      miSelect := '"' || rCol.column_name || '"'; 
    else 
      miSelect := miSelect || ', ' || '"' || rCol.column_name || '"'; 
    end if; 
  end loop; 
  miSelect := 'select ' || miSelect || ' from ' || tOwner || '.' || tName || ';'; 
  dbms_output.put_line(miSelect); 
end;
```

El ejemplo lista todas las columnas de la tabla `CO.PRODUCTS` que tienen una letra 'P' como parte del nombre, del [esquema de ejemplo de oracle live](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/kmahdclh2exfdnciwwblewt9c), donde genera este resultado:

```
select "PRODUCT_ID", "PRODUCT_NAME", "UNIT_PRICE", "PRODUCT_DETAILS", "PRODUCT_IMAGE", "IMAGE_MIME_TYPE", "IMAGE_LAST_UPDATED" from CO.PRODUCTS;
```

Puedes ejecutar el script en línea en [oracle live](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/kmahdclh2exfdnciwwblewt9c).